# WebGL unforms locations are null

Tags: null, webgl, shader, lighting

I'm learning WebGL and I'm quite new to Stack Overflow too. So sorry if I do something wrong. My problem is that lighting doesn't quite work.
I think I isolated the problem. Some of my uniforms locations are null.

Searching for a solution I found out that if variables are not used the compiler optimizes them out. But they are used in my shaders! So I have no clue what else could possibly go wrong.

Here are the shaders I'm using and below I report which variables are being null.
Also interestingly only some of them are null and I can't figure out why they are different. Any help with my shaders would me much appreciated.

```
<script id="shader-f-textcol-per_frag_light" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
 precision mediump float;

 varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
 varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
 varying vec4 vPosition;
 varying vec4 vColor;

 uniform bool uUseAmbientLight;
 uniform bool uUseSpecLight;
 uniform bool uUseDirectLight;
 uniform bool uUsePointLight;

 uniform int  uMode;

 uniform float uMaterialShine;
 uniform float uAlpha;

 uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;

 uniform vec3 uPointLightingLocation;
 uniform vec3 uPointLightingColor;

 uniform vec3 uDirectLightingDirection;
 uniform vec3 uDirectLightingColor;

 uniform sampler2D uSampler;

 void main(void) {

   vec3 ambientColor = uAmbientColor;
   vec3 lightWeighting = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);

   vec3 normal = normalize(vTransformedNormal);    
   vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uPointLightingLocation - vPosition.xyz);

   float directionalLightWeighting = 0.0;
   float specularLightWeighting = 0.0;
   float pointLightWeighting = 0.0;

   if(!uUseAmbientLight)
   {
       ambientColor = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
   }
   if(uUseDirectLight)
   {
       directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(normal, uDirectLightingDirection), 0.0);
   }
   if(uUsePointLight)
   {
       float pointLightWeighting = max(dot(normal, lightDirection), 0.0);

       float specularLightWeighting = 0.0;
       if (uUseSpecLight) {
           vec3 eyeDirection = normalize(-vPosition.xyz);
           vec3 reflectionDirection = reflect(-lightDirection, normal);

           specularLightWeighting = pow(max(dot(reflectionDirection, eyeDirection), 0.0), uMaterialShine);
       }
   }

   lightWeighting = ambientColor + uDirectLightingColor * directionalLightWeighting + uPointLightingColor  * pointLightWeighting + uPointLightingColor  * specularLightWeighting;

   vec4 fragmentColor;
   if (uMode == 0) 
   {
       fragmentColor = vColor;
   }
   else if (uMode == 1)
   {
       fragmentColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
   }
   else 
   {
        fragmentColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t)) * vColor;
   }

   gl_FragColor = vec4(fragmentColor.rgb * lightWeighting, fragmentColor.a*uAlpha);

  }
 </script>

 <script id="shader-v-textcol-per_frag_light" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
 attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
 attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
 attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
 attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

 uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
 uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
 uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

 varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
 varying vec3 vTransformedNormal;
 varying vec4 vPosition;
 varying vec4 vColor;

 void main(void) {
   vPosition = uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
   gl_Position = uPMatrix * vPosition;
   vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
   vTransformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
   vColor = aVertexColor;
    }
   </script>
```

And here is a print of the uniforms.
Only the ones related to point lighting and specular highlights are null.

```
     uMaterialShine null
     uUseSpecularLight null
     uUseAmbientLight [object WebGLUniformLocation]
     uUsePointLight null
     uUseDirectLight [object WebGLUniformLocation]
     uAmbientColor [object WebGLUniformLocation]
     uPointLightingLocation null
     uPointLightingColor null
     uAmbientColor [object WebGLUniformLocation]
     uDirectLighting [object WebGLUniformLocation]
     uDirectLightingDirection [object WebGLUniformLocation]
     uAlpha [object WebGLUniformLocation]
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code where you fetch the uniform locations and set the uniform values?

Comment: Actually I got this problem trying to solve an other one. Now I started again from scratch and I found out the solution to this. I was redefining pointLightWeighting and specularLightWeighting inside the "if". And this triggered the compiler to ignore the external ones.

Comment: But now I'm back with my original problem.

Answer (score 7):

Those uniforms are not used in your shader. Most drivers will optimize out those uniforms therefore they won't have locations.

It is specifically for this reason that calling `gl.uniform???` with a `null` location is a no-op so that when editing shaders if you have code that looks up a uniform that got optimized out your code setting that uniform won't start generating errors.

```
// even if the uniform does not exist this code 
// will not generate an error.
var locationOfMissingLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "foobar");
...
gl.uniform4f(locationOfMissingLocation, r, g, b, a);
```

You should design your code so that it will function whether or not a uniform (or attribute) exists. That way when you're debugging and commenting out parts of your shaders to figure what's wrong your program will still function.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution to this. I was redefining pointLightWeighting and specularLightWeighting inside the "if". This didn't give any compiler error but triggered the compiler to ignore the external ones.